# Under which conditions is $\partial (A \cap B) = (\partial A \cap \bar{B}) \bigcap (\bar{A}\cap\partial B)$

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Drawing some pictures is got the impression that for arbitrary sets $A,B$, the equality
$\partial (A \cap B) = (\partial A \cap \bar{B}) \bigcap (\bar{A}\cap \partial B)$, should hold.

I know that that the "$\subseteq$" direction holds, because $\partial(A\cap B) \subset \partial A \cup \partial B$

The "$\supseteq$" direction however does not hold in genereal. In particualer it does not hold if $A,B$ are disjoint but $\bar{A}, \bar{B}$ are not.
So when does it hold, especially in the case where $A,B$ are not disjoint?

Similarly, under which conditions is $\partial (A \cup B) = (\partial A \cap \bar{B}) \bigcup (\bar{A}\cap \partial B)$?

Answer (score 1):

I take it that $\partial A=\overline A \setminus \text{int}_X A$ for $A\subseteq X$.

If $A$ and $B$ are open, then your equation is equivalent to $$\partial \big(\overline A \cap \overline B \setminus (A\cup B)\big)=\overline A \cap \overline B \setminus (A\cup B),$$ and each side is empty.

If $A$ and $B$ are $\textit{clopen}$, then you see it is true because each side is empty.

Also, if $A$ and $B$ are open and the equation holds, then $\overline A \cap \overline B$ is clopen. So it is a rare property for open sets in a connected space.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to get the left side of this equality?